# Devexpress : Update Checkbox Value When Clicked , Dataset without Database (VB.NET and VS2019)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I created grid using data from dataset, so no database involved, but so far I only able to add row and checkbox, but when I click the checkbox, the value not updated.

```
dtmenu.Columns.Add("Menu")

        dtmenu.Columns.Add("New")
        dtmenu.Columns.Add("Edit")
        dtmenu.Columns.Add("Delete")
        dtmenu.Columns.Add("View")
        dtmenu.Columns.Add("Key")

        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Customer", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Supplier", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Salesman", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Consignee/Shipper", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Shipping Line", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Agent", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Negara", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Charges", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Sea Port", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Air Port", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Currency", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Sea Import", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Sea Export", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Air Import", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Air Export", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Invoices", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Payment from Customer", 1)
        dtmenu.Rows.Add("Payment to Supplier", 1)

        grV.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = True
        grV.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode = GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect
        dtset.Tables.Add(dtmenu)
        'dtSet.Tables(0).Columns(0).ReadOnly = True

        gr.DataSource = dtset
        gr.DataMember = "grMenuGr"
        Dim RpCheck As New DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit
        grV.Columns(1).ColumnEdit = RpCheck
        RpCheck.ValueChecked = Convert.ToSByte(1)
```

Now, How do I make the first column readonly and how to update the checkedit value when I click on  the second column

UPDATE : I read somewhere and I tried to use event from Gridview

```
Private Sub grV_CellValueChanging(sender As Object, e As Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs) Handles grV.CellValueChanging
        If e.Column.FieldName.ToUpper() = "NEW" Then
           MsgBox("checked column Edit")
        ElseIf e.Column.FieldName.ToUpper() = "EDIT" Then
            MsgBox("checked column Edit")
        End If
    End Sub
```

But still the checkbox still won't update,

Comment: Are you using GridView or DataGridView? The 4 columns you added are checkbox column? After that you want the system performs something on check value changed?

Comment: I am using devexpress gridcontrol, quite different from datagridview where you just set boolean type to column and it will convert to checkbox, but I finally solve it. in Devexpress you need to use `repositorycheckedit` and set data type to `boolean` and later set properties `valuechecked` and `valueunchecked` according to value from datatable